# Input to the command tf.nn.conv2d

Tags: tensorflow

I type the following lines in Syder (Anaconda):

```
inlay=np.random.random(size=(1,10,10,3)).astype('float32')
layer=tf.nn.conv2d(inlay,filter=np.array([1,1,3,1]).astype('float32'),strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
```

`'inlay`' suppose to be the input for `tf.nn.conv2d`. However, I got the following
ValueError:

```
"ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 1 for 'Conv2D_21' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [1,10,10,3], [4]".
```

I do not understand. The input `np.array`, `'inlay'`, is a 4D tesnor, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your filter, not your input. Currently it is [1, 1, 3, 1], i.e. it has rank 1. I think you meant a filter with kernel width 1, height 1, input dim 3 and output dim 1? If so try something like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv'):
    w = tf.get_variable(
        'weights',
        shape=[1, 1, 3, 1],
        initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
    )
    inlay = np.random.random(size=(1,10,10,3)).astype('float32')  
    layer = nn.conv2d(inlay, filter=w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')`
```